# Java (Apache POI) How to stretch XWPFTable row across whole page

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a simple XWPFTable I made using Apache POI for docx, but if the text of the cell is short the cell/row resizes to fit around the text. How do I set it so the table/rows stay stretched from left to right of the whole page no matter the length of the text? Thanks.

Here's the table part of the code if It helps:

```
XWPFTable header = document.createTable(1, 3);
        header.getRow(0).getCell(0).setText("LCode");
        header.getRow(0).getCell(1).setText("QTY");
        header.getRow(0).getCell(2).setText("Description/Justification");

        XWPFTable table = document.createTable(LCodes.size(), 3);
        int x = 0;
        for (Map.Entry entry : new TreeMap<Integer, List<String>>(LCodes).entrySet()) {     
            Object LCode = entry.getKey();
            table.getRow(x).getCell(0).setText("L" + LCode);
            table.getRow(x).getCell(1).setText(LCodes.get(LCode).get(2));

            XWPFParagraph para = table.getRow(x).getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                if (i == 1 && LCodes.get(LCode).get(i).trim().equals("")) {
                    continue;
                }
                XWPFRun leading = para.createRun();
                leading.setItalic(true);
                if (i == 0) {
                    leading.setText("Description: ");
                    } else {
                    leading.setText("Justification: ");
                }
                XWPFRun trailing = para.createRun();
                trailing.setText(LCodes.get(LCode).get(i));
                if (i == 0 && !(LCodes.get(LCode).get(i).trim().equals(""))) {
                    trailing.addBreak();
                }
            }
            x++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To stretch width of xwpf table you need to perform following. 
1. Create table in sample xwpf document.
2. Download the same document as zip and extract document.xml file.
3. Find

Another solution: If you dont want to go from all these and your table borders are hidden. You can add below XWPFparagraph in first column of your table and this will do the trick.

```
//add this para in first column to get table width, 84pts total
private XWPFParagraph getFirstColumnText(){
    XWPFParagraph para=new XWPFDocument().createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run=para.createRun();
    run.setColor("ffffff");
    run.setText("...................................................................................");
    return para;
}
```